# Get column data based on foreign key and manytomanyfield in django admin

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am new in Django. I have the following models.

`Category`

```
id      category_name
1       A
2       B
```

`Module` (category_id is the foreignkey)

```
id      module_name    category_id
1       X              1   
2       Y              2
```

`category_user` (user_id is ManyToManyField with category_id)

```
id      category_id    user_id
1       1              23 
2       2              23
```

So I want to display data `X` & `Y` from `module`  in admin category edit page if that category id `1` & `2` is assigned to user `23`.

`admin.py`

```
class categoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('category_name','category_desc')
    filter_horizontal = ('user',)
    readonly_fields = ('allowed_module_names',)

    def allowed_module_names(self, instance):
        modules = []
        module_names = instance.category.values_list("module_name")
        print(module_names)
```

The query returns blank.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you `return`ing the `module_names` variable?

Comment: Before returning I was trying to print the value. It is blank.

Comment: Oh ok. In that case, model definitions over the SQL-like table data will be better. Because from the current question, what I understand is that you are trying `instance.category` on a category instance, which doesn't seem right. You should be doing something like `category_instance.module_set.values_list('module_name')`.

Comment: Getting a name error on category_instance.

Comment: Yes, use only `instance`, I added `category_`for clarity.

Comment: There is an issue. It displays the module names even if no category is assigned to a user.

Comment: You need to add appropriate filters then.

Comment: I tried with `instance.filter(user_id=56).module_set.values_list("module_name", flat=True)`. Is it right way to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154440/discussion-between-ashish-nitin-patil-and-prithviraj-mitra).

Comment: Ok..I am in the room.